# Disable / remove the default input type= "email" validation text overlay in Firefox + Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, placeholder, email-validation

I currently have a e-mail field

```
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
```

Upon submitting / if the field is empty or the email adress doesnt validate correct, a default validation overlay appears in Firefox + Crome.

Ive integrated my own styled validation, so currently its double on the validation for that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You can add `formnovalidate` attribute to the submit input or `novalidate` attribute to the form that contains the input that you don't want to validate.

Comment: I find the `novalidate` option on the ancestor `<form>` element helpful - especially for ASP.NET pages where the cancel button does a postback, yet renders as `type="submit"`.