# i need to disable default validation of input type='email'

Tags: javascript, html

I need to disable default validation of input type='email'
like if I don't write '@' or 'gmail.com' it show me default validation pop up
I need to disable it and create my own pop up for show it using html of JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable / remove the default input type= "email" validation text overlay in Firefox + Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269075/disable-remove-the-default-input-type-email-validation-text-overlay-in-fire)

Comment: I mean, if you're not going to use the features of email, then you should probably just use `type="text"`. On the other hand, I do heavily advise you to ***NOT*** do your own custom validation for emails.

Answer (score 2):

use "novalidate"

"input type="email" novalidate/"

make it type="text", Why you using the type="email", if you don't need its as "email".

Comment: There is at least one reason to use `type="email"` even if you don't want default validation: and that reason is browser autofills.

Comment: The `novalidate` attribute belongs in the form element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#novalidate

Answer (score 0):

you can change the input type from email to text, after that you can get input data with `input` Event listener